# Write a list of files in the Documents folder and keep them in memory

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, save

I have several files to be saved in the Documents folder, this list of files put in a mutable array. The files must remain in the memory of the iPhone application also closed. The first file is saved, but when I change view controllers and then go back the mutable array becomes empty. How do I keep the data in memory in the Documents folder?

in DetailExpViewController.h

```
  //....
  @property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *arrayFavorites;
  @property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL existsArray;
  //....
  @end
```

in DetailExpViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      //.....
      if (!self.existsArray){
          /*when I load the view controller this array is always nil even 
            has already  been created*/

           self.arrayFavorites =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     }else{
          NSLog(@"The array exists");
      }
      //....
 }

 -(void) addFavorites:(id)sender{

     //.....
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
  (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString * text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",self.name];
   NSString * documentsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: text];

   [self.arrayFavorites addObject:text];
   [self.arrayFavorites writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES];
   self.existsArray=YES;

   for (id obj in self.arrayFavorites) {

    NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayFavorites);
    //only writes the file at the time, then it is deleted

  }
```

}

Comment: in view didload array be nil always and then u alloc it

Comment: why dont you use sqlite for storing data always

Comment: Because is only list of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can `save NSArray` in `Document Directory` like [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html).

**Note** : `saving` and `retrieving` `filename` remains `same`.

Its also `easy retrieve` `saved` `array` from `doc dir`.

**EDIT** : If `data` is `complex and large` better use `SQLITE`.

---

**EDIT** : In `view Controller's` Add to `favourite` button click `event`:

```
 //check favourite saved in doc dir
 if(!saved) //not saved
   //NSMutableArray has not data first time
   //[NSMutableArray addObject:newFavourite];
   //save new data in doc dir
 else // saved
   //firstly retrieve data from doc dir as NSMutableArray
   //[NSMutableArray addObject:newFavourite];
   //Now save again NSMutableArray in doc dir.
```

By `following` these `instruction` files remain `permanently` in the `Documents folder`.

Comment: I have a mutable array is not a static array as shown. In my application there is a view controller inside which there is a button called "Add Favorites" if the user presses the button, the file should be saved in the Documents folder, otherwise not. I can not know in advance what will save the user, so I created a mutable array. These files must remain permanently in the Documents folder. How can I do?

Comment: refernce link example shows static data. but u can have dyanamic data